# WordPress error on localhost, XAMPP: "Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found"

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I'm having problems since I updated `Apache` on `Windows 10` from `PHP 7.2` to `PHP 7.4`...

I thought I had everything running. But now when I try to install a plugin, WordPress tells me: `"Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found."`

I did some research and found out that I need to uncomment `extension=curl` and `extension=openssl` in my `php.ini`, which I did. But (after restarting `XAMPP`) it's still not working.

I also found information to add:

```
 Below this line: #LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so

     # load curl and open ssl libraries
      LoadFile “C:\php\libeay32.dll”
      LoadFile “C:\php\ssleay32.dll”
      LoadFile “C:\php\libssh2.dll”

And above this line: <IfModule unixd_module>
```

in the Apache config file. But since I only have the file `libssh2.dll`, Apache won't start after adding these lines.

**Edit:**

I did `echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_init') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';` in xamp/htdocs and it told me that suddenly cURL is disabled...

What else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, never mind, I fixed it. It turns out that

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

in my `php.ini` was disabled as well. After removing the ; everything is working.