# No working transports found - wordpress problem

Tags: php, wordpress, php-extension

I have a Wordpress site on localhost. It has been a few months since I last did any changes on it and now I want to update to a new Wordpress version. When I try to do so, it says "Installation failed. No working transports found.". I have tried to solve the problem with solutions found on internet:

- uncommenting extension=php_curl.dll and extension=php_openssl.dll

and no help. I checked the php extensions and both have a tick next to them.(wamp>php>php extensions)

[image]
[image]
I have also loaded phpinfo() and I get no info on curl, only its author.
I tested if my curl extension is actually working with this code:

```
<?php
var_dump(extension_loaded("curl"));
?>
```

and it loads as - bool(false).

I have also tried uncommenting extension_dir= "ext" from this source: [WordPress error on localhost, XAMPP: "Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465984/wordpress-error-on-localhost-xampp-installation-failed-download-failed-no-w)
and it loads me whole another fatal error

I have tried solutions on this site: https://www.howtosolutions.net/2021/09/fixing-php-curl-extension-not-loading-when-enabled-windows/
and still, I have the same problem from the beggining.

Help?

Comment: If these extensions don't show up as enabled anywhere, you didn't enable them properly

Comment: _"I checked the php extensions and both have a tick next to them."_ - checked where, and "tick" meaning what?

Comment: Have you checked whether you are modifying the _correct_ php.ini in the first place? The phpinfo output shows you which one was actually used in the top part.

Comment: @cbroe i have put an image and checked the php.ini file, the right one, from phpinfo output, that one i have modified the whole time

Comment: And what exactly _is_ that, what your screenshot shows? Where/in what are you checking your PHP extensions there?

Comment: sorry for not being clear..

Comment: "WampServer 2.5" sounds a bit suspicious to me. Are you really using an nine years old version of WampServer?